# Determine Filename of Unzipped File

Tags: python, python-3.x, unzip

Say you unzip a file called `file123.zip` with `zipfile.ZipFile`, which yields an unzipped file saved to a known path. However, this unzipped file has a completely random name. How do you determine this completely random filename? Or is there some way to control what the name of the unzipped file is?
I am trying to implement this in python.

Comment: Doesn't the unzipped file have the same name as the zipped one?

Comment: No, it does not. And what I meant to say was that the unzipped file name is completely arbitrary and not random, as @mhawke said below

Comment: @iknowfrench: in that case, is there something about my answer that doesn't solve your problem? You can choose your own file name, and the file names are available in `namelist()`.

Comment: @mhawke absolutely not, your code solved my problem perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

By *"random"* I assume that you mean that the files are named arbitrarily.

You can use [`ZipFile.read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.read) which unzips the file and returns its contents as a string of bytes. You can then write that string to a named file of your choice.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('file123.zip') as zf:
    for i, name in enumerate(zf.namelist()):
        with open('outfile_{}'.format(i), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(zf.read(name))
```

This will write each file from the archive to a file named `output_n` in the current directory. The names of the files contained in the archive are obtained with [`ZipFile.namelist()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist). I've used `enumerate()` as a simple method of generating the file names, however, you could substitute that with whatever naming scheme you require.

Answer (score 0):

If the filename is completely random you can first check for all filenames in a particular directory using [os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir). Now you know the filename and can do whatever you want with it :)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory) topic for more information.